# Familiar Five (r&r ignored)

Tags: logical-deduction, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

**What is the correct option/answer to this puzzle?**

---

[image]

Comment: Note that the five tetromino shapes are commonly called L, I, T, S, O. The squiggly shape is S and the square is O. Looks like this puzzle is using a different coding, which then should be explicitly mentioned in the puzzle.

Comment: Aah, I was unsure of the "o" and "s". But after a quick google search i found "z" and just left the square to be a square, "s".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well...

> Assuming that these are tetronimoes, the grid can be filled in like this:
>  [image]
>  using the knowledge that red is a square and grey is a line... the rest are pretty much forced.
>
>  Converting shapes back into their standard letters, we get L Z T S X T S T T  around the central black square!
>  Which is option B?

I should have noted:

> While solving I wasn't able to keep the colours apart, so I assume that there is a reason for that in the title? (which I thought was Rotations and Reflections, but I may be incorrect).

Comment: No, you are correct, well done.

Comment: Where are you converting the shapes from? I can understand how given a set of shapes you could get those letters, but I'm unclear on which sequence of shapes you converted, and where you got them from.

Comment: @bobble consider the 3x3 subgrid centered on the black square. Now, in the completed puzzle, consider what shape each cell in that 3x3 grid is a part of. This answer lists them in reading order (with X as the black square).

Comment: Updated answer to be clearer, sorry :)